# Cannot view taxonomy terms for one vocabulary

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm running core 8.9.16 (and have run database updates) and have 24 vocabularies. One is giving me an error when I try to list terms, the others are fine. This seems to have happened when I updated to 8.9.1.  But when using the contrib taxonomy manager module, I can list the terms. I don't know if this is a core issue, or perhaps corrupted data in the table. I'd appreciate any tips on how to solve this. Here's the error screen:

```
Error: Call to a member function id() on null in Drupal\taxonomy\TermStorage->loadTree() (line 276 of core/modules/taxonomy/src/TermStorage.php).

Drupal\taxonomy\TermStorage->loadTree('team_member_types', 0, 1, 1) (Line: 177)
Drupal\taxonomy\Form\OverviewTerms->buildForm(Array, Object, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 532)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->retrieveForm('taxonomy_overview_terms', Object) (Line: 278)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm(Object, Object) (Line: 91)
Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 573)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 151)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 708)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Here's what I've found running it through debug (in phpStorm); line 276 is

```
if (isset($this->treeParents[$vid][$load_entities ? $term->id() : $term->tid])) {
```

`$load_entities` is true
`$term` is null, though

In line 275, $term is loaded:

```
$term = $load_entities ? $term_entities[$child] : $this->treeTerms[$vid][$child];
```

`$child` is set to 54, which is a non-existent term. The term was somehow deleted. I don't recall deleting it. It is set in line 270:

```
$child = current($this->treeChildren[$vid][$parent])
```

and it is set to 54 at the end of the loop by looking at the next value. The values in `$this->treeChildren[$vid][$parent]` are 53, 54, 67, 72, 68

If this is mangled data, how do I remove the 54?

Comment: Let's figure out how this is mangled. Is TID 54 present in all or some of the database tables taxonomy_term_data, taxonomy_term_revision, taxonomy_term_field_data, and taxonomy_term_field_revision?

Comment: Yes, it was in taxonomy_term_field_data; removing it solved the problem. Thanks so much for your help.